# Undefined variable when looping data in codeigniter view

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I get the error shown below when I tried to loop my data/value in my View page.

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: tasks
>
> Filename: pages/all.php
>
> Line Number: 2

**application/controllers/task.php**

```
public function show() {
      $data['tasks'] = $this->Tasks_model->show_task()->result();
      $this->load->view('pages/all', $data);
}
```

**application/models/Tasks_model.php**

```
public function show_task() {
     return $this->db->get('task');
}
```

**application/views/pages/all**

```
<?php
    foreach($tasks as $task) {
?>
    <span><?php echo $task->title ?></span>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: `return $this->db->get('task')->result();`

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile still the same error

Comment: Before `foreach`, always check if that foreach array exists or not. `if( isset($tasks) && ( is_array($tasks) && count($tasks)>0 ) ) { //foreach code here }`. Also by initially, you can set `$data['tasks'] = array();` in first line of `function show()`.

Comment: thx @VirenPanchal , you help me with my error. But now, i can't loop my data. How do i get the things inside the array ?

Comment: @BeingShame In controller `function show()`, see what you are getting `/*echo"<pre>"; print_r($this->data['tasks']); die();*/` and print results accordingly in View foreach loop.

Comment: Still can't display the data. I think, i don't understand your explanation enough @VirenPanchal

Comment: Please uncomment this `/*echo"<pre>"; print_r($tasks); die();*/` in view file and see what you are getting. After getting desired array comment it again.

Comment: i get "Undefined variable: tasks" error again after using your code @VirenPanchal

Comment: Controller => `public function show() {
   $data['tasks'] = array();
      $data['tasks'] = $this->Tasks_model->show_task()->result();
      $this->load->view('pages/all', $data);
}`    View => 
`<?php
 if( isset($tasks) && ( is_array($tasks) && count($tasks)>0 ) ) {
 //echo"<pre>"; print_r($tasks); die();
    foreach($tasks as $task) {
?>
    <span><?php echo $task->title ?></span>
<?php }  } ?>`

Comment: there's no error, but i still can't get the loop data from the tasks. it's still empty. sorry @VirenPanchal